# Multiple database records

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I want to store emergency help line contacts in database from ASP.NET web site . . .this contacts will be assign to particular locations of different cities. . .
For eg: City=Mumbai and then for Mumbai City there will be various locations like Dadar, Andheri, Borivali , etc .

I have designed a form [image]

now, the problem is that , there can be one airport for multiple locations of a particular city then also i have to enter the entire information for each and every location . . . So is there any way to avoid multiple entries ?

Comment: Why cant you keep Airport name in textbox and keep it disabled? Will this be ok?

Comment: Just enable to select one of the existing airports in a `DropDownList`. You have to link them with foreign-keys in `tblLocation` to `tblAirport`.

Comment: Please tell us how does your table look like? Give schema

Comment: I think you need to breakdown your database tables in some more tables, i think after that you can achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following table schema, and design you form accordingly

**Location Table**

```
LocationID (Primary Key)
CountryID (Foreign Key)
CityID (Foreign Key)
ContactID (Foreign Key)
Location
```

**City Table**

```
CityID(Primary Key)
City
```

**Country Table**

```
CountryID(Primary Key)
Country
```

**Service Table**

```
ServiceID(Primary Key)
Service         --Airport/Ambulance/fire...
```

**Contact Table**

```
ContactID (Primary Key)
ServiceID (Foreign Key)
Description    --AirportName/HospitalName
Contact        --Contact Number
```

**UPDATE (Form Design Tips)**

1. Form to add records to City/Country/Service Tables (They are quite simple you just need to check duplicate entry/ Required fields.
2. For Contact Table use Drop Down for Service that is populated from `Service Table`
3. For Location use Drop Downs for Country,City and Contact that are populated from respective tables.
4. Use `INNER JOINS` to join the tables and display the desired Results

Comment: but there are multiple helpline services like airport,ambulance,police,fire,etc . . .

Comment: can you help me in designing the form ,please . . .

Comment: i have added some tips for form design, have a look